# PHP foreach array into option value

Tags: php, html-select

Without needing to give too much info on the API in use, I'm trying to get the *option value* to match what's being wrapped inside the option tag.

Something like this:

```
<option value="Foo">Bar</option>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local', array(
    "AreaCode" => $_POST["areacode"]));
    echo "<select>";
    foreach($numbers->available_phone_numbers as $number) {
        echo "<option value=''>";
        echo $number->phone_number;
        $counter++;
        echo "</option>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $counter;
?>
```

With this form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Area Code:<br>
    <input type="text" name="areacode" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't put `<br>` inside a select, and you need to add `value` to each option: `echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($number->phone_number) . "'>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
echo '<select>';
foreach($numbers->available_phone_numbers as $number) {

    echo '<option value="' .$number->phone_number .'">';
    echo $number->phone_number;
    echo '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Also, you shouldn't have a `br` tag in your `select` element.

Comment: You should always wrap values that go into an attribute with [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) - In case the value contains characters such as `"` or `>` or others that might break the html structure - But the answer is correct in the overall

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo "<option value=''>";` to `echo "<option value='{$number->phone_number}'>";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the select inside the form tag in order to submit the selected data also.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
echo "<select>";
foreach($numbers->available_phone_numbers as $number) {

echo "<option value='".$number->phone_number."'>";
echo $number->phone_number;
$counter++;
echo "</option>";
echo "<br>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br>";
echo $counter;
?>Area Code:<br>
<input type="text" name="areacode" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$numbers = $client->account->available_phone_numbers->getList('US', 'Local',        
array(
"AreaCode" => $_POST["areacode"]
));
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<?php
echo "<select>";
foreach($numbers->available_phone_numbers as $number) {
echo "<option>" . $number->phone_number . "</option>";
$counter++;
}
echo "</select>";

?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```